# how string custom processing by "special characters" is called in programming?

Tags: php, string

In programming, strings like these

```
$stringA="[[f9.heart]]"; // facebook replaces it with heart image
$stringB="%%VARNAME%%"; // set var value into a template system
```

are defined to have a special processing (set by the developers). What is the correct computer term to refer them as? (when making internet research)

If someone knows a link to good-practices, recommendations etc for PHP, please post them! Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an extremely common thing and has many names in different contexts.

I can think of

- variable expansion (*shell scripting*)
- macro expansion, substitution variables (*other scripts*)
- escape sequences (*tangentially*)
- template expansion/template text generation (*document generation*)
- string interpolation (*programming languages* eg. ruby, perl, python)
- string concatenation (most broad)

PS: late arrival:

- splicing (as in [Boo's syntactic macros](http://bamboo.github.io/), e.g.)

If referring to the actual string formats:

- variable references
- field references/field code
- format string

Comment: a lot of edits! ahah good!, i think string-interpolation is what i am looking for (( im under php development ))